# type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Map<String, dynamic>>'

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm little bit stuck on some situation.

1) `type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Map<String, dynamic>>'`

**My code.**

```
List<Map<String, dynamic>> arrayOfProductList = List<Map<String, dynamic>>();
```

**Calling APIs**

```
Future<Map<String, dynamic>> _callWebServiceForGetProductList() async{

    String strURL = 'http:xxxxxx/productlist.php';
    Map<String, String> headerDic = {"Authorization": "ff624bc580ab48a3910d4352dxxx712"};
    Map<String, String> paramDic = {"page": "1", "search": "", "term_id": ""};

    http.Response httpRes = await http.post(strURL, headers: headerDic, body: paramDic);
    Map<String, dynamic> responseDic = json.decode(httpRes.body);
    return responseDic;
  }
```

**`FutureBuilder` Widget and stuff**

```
Expanded(
              child: Container(
                child: FutureBuilder(
                    future: _callWebServiceForGetProductList(),
                    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snap) {
                    if(snap.hasData) {
                      Map<String, dynamic> dicOfData = snap.data;
                      arrayOfProductList = dicOfData["data"] as List<Map<String, dynamic>>;
                      print(arrayOfProductList);
                      _setupProductListView();
                    }
                    else if(snap.hasError) {
                      showDialog(context: context, builder:(_) => AlertDialog(
                        content: Text("Error ${snap.hasError.toString()}"),
                        title: Text("Error"),
                      ));
                    }
                    return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());

                    }
                ),
              ),
            )
```

I'm googling for last 2 hours but didn't get any result. Where i'm going wrong? Guide me.

Comment: Try reading the error message. `_InternalLinkedHashMap` is the same as `Map` (just an internal representation). The value is a `Map<String,dynamic>` and the type you try to assgn to is a `List<Map<String,dynamic>>`. So you expect a list bat the actual value is not a list, it's a single value.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Sorry I'm new at Flutter. I know that can't able to cast the list but how can I solve it. Means Map<String, dynamic> has key ..name is "data" and This key has List<Map<String, dynamic>> (Array of dictionary). How should I write it?

Comment: So instead of declare List<Map<String, dynamic>>. I have to declare just   var arrayOfProductList; ?

Comment: Can you please post single page app demo  with simple working api call?

Comment: try using as List without  generic definition <Map<String,dynamic>> just remove it ,let me know if this solved the issue

Comment: or `Map<String, dynamic> arrayOfProductList`. If you use `var` you just get the inferred type. If you expect a list but get a map `var` only delays the error. You need to figure out why the data you get and the data you expect are different.

Comment: ```Map<String, dynamic>.from(json.decode(httpRes.body));```
You can try this as well.

Answer (score 0):

The cast attempt on `dicOfData["data"] as List<Map<String, dynamic>>` seems to have caused the type mismatch error you received. If you can provide more details on the data the snapshot contains, this can help us identify why it causes the error.